# How Can i Remove "[EXTRACT] " tag from extracted data in Imacros

Tags: imacros

I have created this imacros script to scrape usernames via blog-plug, it generates a list of username in this format

```
[EXTRACT]BlogOne[EXTRACT]
[EXTRACT]BlogTwo[EXTRACT]
[EXTRACT]BlogThree[EXTRACT]
```

How Can i get the blog list in proper format i.e.

```
BlogOne
BlogTwo
BlogThree
```

Here is the Imacros code i wrote to scrape the blogname list

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
URL GOTO=http://blog-plug.com/wallofportraits.php

'New tab opened
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:*api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/*/avatar/64 EXTRACT=ALT
ADD !EXTRACT <BR>
TAG POS=2 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:*api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/*/avatar/64 EXTRACT=ALT
ADD !EXTRACT <BR>
TAG POS=3 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:*api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/*/avatar/64 EXTRACT=ALT
ADD !EXTRACT <BR>

SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line seems to be helpful:

```
SET !CLIPBOARD EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\[EXTRACT\\]/g, '');")
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution on iMacros Forums, This solved my problem :)

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
URL GOTO=http://blog-plug.com/wallofportraits.php

'New tab opened
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:*api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/*/avatar/64 EXTRACT=ALT
SET My_Data {{!EXTRACT}}<BR>

SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=2 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:*api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/*/avatar/64 EXTRACT=ALT
ADD My_Data {{!EXTRACT}}<BR>

SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=3 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:*api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/*/avatar/64 EXTRACT=ALT
ADD My_Data {{!EXTRACT}}<BR>

SET !CLIPBOARD {{My_Data}}
```